# Iterating filter: How do I filter a list for multiple tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, filter

I'm working on this problem and I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to generate a list using `filter`. I've added `prints` to my code see what's going wrong, and `filter` seems to be concerned with only the last tuple in my list. For example, if I have a list of tuples say `[(4,1),(16,3),(32,11)]` `filter` only filters all the elements in `residuelist` : `x%32!=11`. I'm new to the `filter` function, so maybe that is its purpose. Is it possible to iterate it over a list of tuples?

My attempt at trying to solve this was to add a `for`

```py
residuelist=range(1,x+1)
for z in requirements:
            for a,b in z:
                residuelist=filter(lambda x: x%a!=b,residuelist)
residuelist=list(residuelist)
```

But `h(5)` shows that `residuelist` is filtered using only the last element in `requirements`:

```py
h(5)
[1, 2] #unfiltered because requirements=[]
[1, 2, 3, 4] #unfiltered because requirements=[]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8] #filtered with (4,1) because requirements=[(4,1)]
[2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16] #filtered with (4,1) because requirements=[(4,1)]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
#filtered with (16,3) because requirements=[(4,1),(16,3)]
[[(4, 1)], [(16, 3)], [(32, 1)], [(32, 5)], [(32, 11)], [(32, 13)], [(32, 17)], [(32, 21)], [(32, 23)], [(32, 25)], [(32, 29)]]
```

Nevermind the double bracketing in `[(x,y)]`, that is the only way I can get the function to work for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is Python 3, `filter` is lazy; it doesn't actually filter a thing until you try to iterate the result. As such, the `a` and `b` it sees aren't the ones that existed when you called `filter`, it's whatever `a` and `b` are when the iterator is run out (when you `list`ify it outside the loop). Simplest fix is to make `a` and `b` into defaulted arguments to the `lambda` so they bind at definition time, not runtime:

```
residuelist = range(1, x+1)
for z in requirements:
    for a, b in z:
        residuelist = filter(lambda x, a=a, b=b: x % a != b, residuelist)  # a=a, b=b binds current definitions of a and b
residuelist = list(residuelist)
```